# Tuning "Steinway Grand Piano" in Garageband midi library like a real piano

Tags: piano, midi, garage-band

I would like to my midi in Garageband sound [like a real piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYcI1A6rBjg) .
I'm using the Steinway Grand Piano in the library, but it has no intonation and depth.
I tried adding some plug-ins and tuning hyperparameters but still, it sounds very midi-generated.

If you know a nice tuning method for the Steinway Grand Piano, please share it with me.

Comment: Piano is a relatively easy to reproduce as a virtual instrument. If you're unhappy with what you have, maybe you need a better instrument? But for natural sound, it is also critical to program or record MIDI well, including nuances like dynamics and timing. Are you aware of that?

Comment: A sampled piano should already be in stretch tuning. It would make no sense to artificially retune it to regular equal temperament.

Comment: @user1079505 Thank you. Okay, then I gonna try to program well. What parameter do you think is critical? Or tell me your favorite plug-in tunings

Comment: @Tetsujin True. But the original one is too systematic. I want it to sound warm, just as people playing a real piano

Comment: Tip: You've used the word "tuning" a couple of times, and I'm starting to think you mean it in a general way, like "tweaking," adjusting parameters. You also used the word "intonation." Most people assume that these two words are talking about the pitch frequency of notes, that is, the way a piano tuner "tunes" a piano, making the notes higher or lower. This is almost certainly not the difference between your patch and a real piano. I wonder whether you can identify any more clearly what it is you feel is lacking?

Comment: It would be helpful to include not only a video with the sound you'd like, but a video (or other recording) of the sound you're getting, for comparison.

Comment: @SpaceTAKA, I suggest listening to the Modartt/Pianoteq demos https://www.modartt.com/ . To my knowledge it's currently the only commercial product, which uses physical models to generate sound of various instruments. You can hear it, and it's quite addictive ... How good it cooperates with Garageband has to be tried. // They describe their technology in some detail, e.g. here: https://www.modartt.com/pianoteq_features#tutorial .

Answer (score 1):

What @Tetsujin is hinting at is: getting a "human" feel is probably not going to be about any setting so much as the control of the notes themselves. In a human performance, in most genres, hardly ever will any two consecutive notes be the same volume (in MIDI terms, "velocity"). The performer will make expressive choices to get louder and softer over time, or when playing simultaneous notes, to make certain ones louder than others. They will also expressively vary the note duration: A quarter note does not mean releasing the key after *exactly* one beat; it may be much less (staccato), or could overlap the next note by a tiny bit.

To use a metaphor: If you're trying to use a computerized text-to-speech app to create spoken poetry, then if it doesn't sound human, the problem is not necessarily that you need a better sample of a human voice, or that the voice needs to be "tuned." It's that we vary every syllable in pitch inflection and emphasis to convey meaning. The classic stereotypical "robot voice" is all about making the pitch and emphasis of all syllables neutral. To make matters harder, these variances are systematic; if you were to just vary the inflection of your speech synthesis randomly it might sound even more bizarre. Certain speech patterns convey certain meanings; we learn them organically, and to spell them out in detail would be a big task.

Similarly, programming an "expressive, human" performance from scratch is a big job. It means fiddling with the velocity and duration of every note, and it means having some intuitive sense of where the music should get louder, softer, more sustained or more detached. That's why, even with MIDI data, it's easiest to input a live performance and then edit as needed. If that isn't feasible for your purposes, you might want to have a pianist audio-record the music as a guide to you.

Comment: Could what is begin sought be a better sound output gear?  If the MIDI keyboard is not connected to a quality PA, the full quality of sound will not be produced. I would suggest at least using a portable PA with a column containing a speaker array mounted to a base with controls and  woofer.  If only headphones, computer speakers, or a small bluetooth speaker are used to hear the MIDI piano, the quality of sound will be lacking.